# Pytorch gridsample - Different Resolutions?

Tags: pytorch

Does Pytorch gridsample work for this particular case.

I have an image of size [B, 100, 200] that I want to map into a smaller [B, 50, 60] space. I have the pixel 1-1 mappings stored in a [B, 100, 200, 2] tensor where most of it i guess is 0?

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, it is possible! But not just with the `gridsample`.

You can check the documentation here:

`grid_sample`: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#grid-sample

`interpolate`: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#interpolate

You will need the following:

```
import torch.nn.F as F
warped_img = F.grid_sample(input, grid)
small_img = F.interplate(warped_img, size=(50, 60))
```

`input` that is the image you have [B, 100, 200];

`grid` it is the 1-1 pixel mapping [B, 100, 200, 2], the values should be normalized in the range [-1, 1] with (-1, -1) being the leftmost upper corner. Notice that, if most of the values are zeros, most pixels will be mapped to the center of the image. That is because `grid` takes the *end_location* of each pixel, it does not take the displacement.

`warped_img = F.grid_sample(input, grid)`

Now, to downsize the image you have to use `F.interpolate`

`small_img = F.interpolate(warped_img, size=(56, 60))`

Notice that you can also downsize first (not sure how that will impact the end-result). That is because the grid is normalized!

```
import torch.nn.F as F
warped_img = F.grid_sample(F.interplate(input, size=(50, 60)), 
                           F.interplate(grid, size=(50, 60)))
```

Notice that grid is the *end location* of each pixel. And it is not the displacement. If you have a flow field (just the displacement of each pixel) you can turn that into a grid with the following:

```
def warp(img, flow, size):
    B, C, H, W = img.size()

    # mesh grid
    grid_x = torch.arange(W, device=img.device)
    grid_y = torch.arange(H, device=img.device)
    yy, xx = torch.meshgrid(grid_y, grid_x)
    grid = torch.cat((xx.unsqueeze(0), yy.unsqueeze(0)), dim=0)

    vgrid = grid + flow.clamp(min=-1000., max=1000.)

    # scale grid to [-1,1]
    vgrid[:, 0, :, :] = 2.0 * vgrid[:, 0, :, :].clone() / max(W - 1, 1) - 1.0
    vgrid[:, 1, :, :] = 2.0 * vgrid[:, 1, :, :].clone() / max(H - 1, 1) - 1.0

    vgrid = vgrid.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
    warped_img = F.grid_sample(img, vgrid, align_corners=False)
    small_img = F.interpolate(warped_img, size=size)

    return small_img
```